ProGuard Rules Not Recognizing Methods Inside Companion Object
I cannot access the companion object methods in my activity B and class A even though I added the proguard rule for activity or activity companion object's methods ?
hear is my code:
class A private constructor(
    private val hostApplication: Application,
    private var cmlOptions: xxx
) {

    companion object {
      
        fun init(
            application: Application,
            cmlOptions: xxx
        ) {
          ...
        }

        suspend fun getVideos(
            params: xxx,
            onReceived: xxx
        ) {
          ...
        }

        suspend fun getLiveEvents(
            params: xxx,
            onReceived: xxx
        ) {
           ...
        }

        suspend fun getTags(
            params: xxx,
            onReceived: xxx
        ) {
          ...
        }

        fun setPlayerUIOptions(options: xxx) {
            ...
        }

        fun getPlayerUIOptions(): xxx? {
           ...
        }

        fun setChatOptions(options: xxx?) {
           ...
        }

        fun getChatOptions(): xxx? {
            ...
        }
    }
 ...

I try to access class A's suspend functions for example getVideos, getLiveEvents, getTags and also init function but I couldn't access them even I added proguard rules
class B : BaseActivity() {
    companion object {
      
        fun start(context: Context, cmlPlayerParams: xxx, cmlPlayerUIOptions: xxx? = null, cmlChatOptions: xxx? = null) {
            ....
        }
    }
   ...

The same thing applies to the companion object in class B. I cannot access the start function in class B, so I added a rule for that too.
some rules that I tried :
1 -
-keepclassmembers class A {
    public static ** Companion;
}
-keepclassmembers class B {
    public static ** Companion;
}

2 -
-keep class A { *; }
-keep class B { *; }

3 -
 -keep class A$Companion { *; }
 -keep class B$Companion { *; }

4 -
-keep class A
-keep class B

5 -
Class A and Class B
I also added Keep anotation to Class B's and A's Companion object
@Keep
companion object {

It seems like Proguard is having a hard time seeing the companion object. I don't understand why it doesn't see it?
